# Problemas con librerías com.sun.org.apache.xml en Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

Estoy realizando un proyecto que incluye manejo de librerías para manipular XML (JAXB,DOM) y utilizo las clases OutputFormat y XMLSerializer y no logro quitar los errores de importación de eclipse y ya tengo instalado Web Tools Platform, no se si el error lo tengo en la configuración del Build Path o donde es que tengo que mirar...Alguien sabe como solucionar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso ocurre generalmente cuando no tienes incluidos en el proyecto los archivos de esas librerías. O cuando los has puesto en el sitio equivocado.

Comment: Eso intuyo, el caso es que no se como solventarlo,  donde voy a buscar esos archivos?

Comment: Hay varias formas de incluir librerías en Java. Debes decidirte por una de ellas y si tienes problemas concretos puedes preguntar aquí. O, si ya tienes una forma de incluir las librerías agréga ese dato a la pregunta y podremos ayudarte mejor.